# Rspec SimpleCov NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, simplecov

When running my rails 4 rspec suite via `rake` everything works correctly but when attempting to run `rake simplecov` I get hundreds of failures all w/ a `NoMethodError` something like:

```
  1) Answer Validations
     Failure/Error: it { should validate_presence_of :text }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `validate_presence_of' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_16::Nested_1:0x007faf9fb5b7c8>
     # ./spec/models/answer_spec.rb:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Any clues as to why this is happening? I should also mention that I'm testing using `sqlite3 :memory:`.

Answer (score 1):

The [shoulda](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda) libraries aren't being included in your simplecov run.

Is simplecov run in a different environment than `:test` perhaps?  That may make the shoulda gem not be loaded if it's only in the `:test` group in your Gemfile.

How are you including simplecov in your spec_helper?  Something like this?

```
require 'simplecov'
require 'simplecov-rcov'
SimpleCov.formatter = SimpleCov::Formatter::RcovFormatter
SimpleCov.start 'rails' if ENV['COVERAGE']
```

As the **very first lines** of your `spec_helper.rb`?

Something like this in your Gemfile?

```
group :test, :development do
  ...
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
end

group :test do
  gem 'simplecov'
  gem 'simplecov-rcov'
end
```

And executing it like so?

```
$ COVERAGE=true bundle exec rake spec
```

This recipe is working very well for me in many projects.  The RCov formatter may not be important depending on your purposes.